# Sum selected rows/columns and replace them with the sum

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the code:

```
pos = {2, 3, 5};
tbl = Table[i*j, {i, 6}, {j, 3}];
totRow = Total /@ tbl[[pos]];
```

which defines some row indices (pos) and a table and some of all rows given by indices pos. However, I would like to do in mathematica way (so probably no fors) sum those rows and replace them by that single total row, which in my example has the name totRow. What is the most effective way. I was thinking succession of drop, join but is there a better way?

To supply an example:

```
pos = {2, 3, 5};
tbl = Table[i*j, {i, 6}, {j, 3}];
totRow = Total /@ tbl[[pos]];
finTbl = Join[Delete[tbl, Partition[pos, 1]], {totRow}];
totRow
TableForm[tbl]
TableForm[finTbl]
```

gives an idea, the three rows from `tbl` at indices given by `pos` are deleted and the `totRow` added. So this works but looks clumsy, I am just curious whether there is proper or better way.

UPDATE:
I changed the examples so that the original table is made of `i*j` for better legibility.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on this: do you want to replace *each* of those rows with a copy of `totRow`? Or do you want to get rid of all of those rows and replace, say, the first with `totRow`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I want to get rid of all the rows indices of which are specified by `pos` and add the row `totRow`, so I have the idea of drop + join, but I am wondering whether it can be done compactly and effectively...

Comment: I don't understand. Please try to be more explicit

Comment: Right: perhaps an example with the expected output would be helpful. But, perhaps this? `Append[Part[tbl, Complement[Range@Length@tbl, pos]], 
 Total[tbl[[pos]], {2}]]`

Comment: Or `Append[Delete[tbl, {#} & /@ pos], Total[tbl[[pos]], {2}]]`.

Comment: Well, personally I feel the position of `totRow` quite strange. Why placing it in the last line? Something like `tbl[[pos]] = Total /@ tbl[[pos]]; tbl` is more intuitive in my opinion.

Comment: `Append[#1[[Complement[Range@Length@#1, #2]]], 
   Total[#[[#2]], {2}]] &[tbl, pos]`, where *tbl* and *pos* are the table and position list. Edit: Actually, just saw *march*'s comment - that's cleaner...

Comment: @xzczd your solution is great visually but does not work. First it sums along the rows not columns and second, it produces something like `{{1, 2, 3}, 10, 20, {4, 8, 12}, 30, {6, 12, 18}}` for the table constructed as `tbl = Table[i*j, {i, 6}, {j, 3}];`. So it does not insert a single row but rather inserts individual elements of the result into each of the original rows. But it would be great if this approach would work.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't meet your requirement, I just mean I personally think forming such a mixed list isn't a very good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer:**

```
(*Generate table*)
table = Table[RandomReal[], {6}, {3}];

(*Declare positions*)
pos = {2, 3, 5};

(*Carry out addition, removal and modification*)
Append[Delete[table, Partition[pos, 1]], #] &[Total@# &[table[[#]] & /@ pos]]
```

**Reference:**
[Append](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html?q=Append)
[Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)
[RandomReal](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html?q=RandomReal)
[Delete](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html?q=Delete)
[Partition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html?q=Partition)
[Total](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html?q=Total)
[@ | /@ | # etc.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it seems just fine.  If you want to make it less clear what you are doing, and add some shorthand notation you could rewrite it like this:

```
finTbl = tbl~Delete~Transpose@{pos}~Join~{Total /@ tbl[[pos]]}
```

(it hurts my brain to try and read code written using infix notation, but I was trying to do it with the smallest number of characters)

Answer (score 1):

As an oneliner. You don't need `Table` to create a random matrix

```
Append[Delete@##, Plus @@@ Extract@##] & @@ {RandomReal[1, {6, 3}], List /@ {2, 3, 5}};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f[table_, pos_] := Append[Delete[table, List /@ pos], Tr /@ table[[pos]]]

finTbl = f[tbl, pos]
```